# ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback called several times

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

I have a strange problem where I register my iOS-app to listen to changes in the phones address book. The correct method is called when something changes in the address book but it gets called 2 - 6 times.

When the object gets created (singleton, so only one object), I register for notifications with this code:

```
ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(notificationAddressBook, addressBookChanged, (__bridge_retained  void *)self);
```

The method that is called looks like this:

```
void addressBookChanged(ABAddressBookRef ab, CFDictionaryRef info, void *context){
ABAddressBookRevert(ab);

    NSLog(@"ADDRESSBOOK CHANGED");
    [phoneBookCopy updateCopy];
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I also have this problem. Every time I switch over to the iOS address book to change the name of a contact and switch back to my app, the callback is called four times - always. I tried adding a context when I registered and I see that my context is sent to me in all four calls.

I read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116956/gcd-and-callbacks-concurrency-issue that somebody claims that this is a known bug but I have not found it. Does anybody have more information on this irritating behavior?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
void addressBookChanged(ABAddressBookRef ab, CFDictionaryRef info, void *context){
ABAddressBookRevert(ab);

    NSLog(@"ADDRESSBOOK CHANGED");
    [phoneBookCopy updateCopy];
    CFRelease(ab);
}
```

It was helped for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem awhile ago, and I had to solve it by creating a NSTimer to handle the duplicate callbacks:

```
[self.changeTimer invalidate];
self.changeTimer = nil;
self.changeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0
                                                            target:self
                                                          selector:@selector(handleAdressBookExternalCallbackBackground)
                                                          userInfo:nil
                                                           repeats:NO];
```

Comment: I think you are calling the method:  ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback   multiple times.

Comment: Sorry, @Z S , I found I was wrong about this, you are right, sorry for down voted on this answer!!!!

Comment: Just a small improvement, ZS code will run the handler only after timer expires, you can check if changeTimer is nil, if it is handle notification and start the timer. The timer should call a selector that sets changeTimer = nil, so we'll handle the next notification after timeout expires

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The callback would only be called once the first time, but if I went out and made changes to the addressbook a second time, then it would be called multiple times. 
For me, the problem was the method that held the `ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback` was being called in the appDelegate's `applicationWillResignActive:` method.

The way I was using the addressbook was for a sync setting. The problem was, I was registering the external callback everytime the sync settings were being *saved*, rather than only when the sync settings were being *changed*.

To illustrate, here is the code I was calling in the appDelegate

```
- (void)saveSettings
{
NSUserDefaults *syncSettingsData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[syncSettingsData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.isSyncingiPadContacts] forKey:SYNC_IPAD_CONTACTS_TURNED_ON];
[self setAddressBookChanged];
[syncSettingsData synchronize];
}

- (void)setAddressBookChanged
{
    if (self.isSyncingiPadContacts)
    {
        ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(self.addressBook, addressBookChanged, (__bridge void *)self);
    }
    else
    {
        ABAddressBookUnregisterExternalChangeCallback(self.addressBook, addressBookChanged, (__bridge void *) self);
    }
}
```

I removed the call to `setAddressBookChanged` in the `saveSettings` method, and just had it called when the addressbook was being created (first time set up) and whenever the user changed the sync settings.

Hopefully this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was quite simple and it works, not only for this but for all the repeated callbacks (including the local notifications repeated calls):
I keep a property with the last call time and check the time interval.
Hope it helps, for me it did the job.

AppDelegate* delegate = (__bridge AppDelegate*)context;

```
if (delegate.lastCall==nil) {
    delegate.lastCall = [[NSDate alloc]init];
}
else {
    NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:delegate.lastCall];
    if (interval<20) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        delegate.lastCall = [[NSDate alloc]init];
    }
}
```

Comment: good logic but this works or not in case of multiple contact syncing in background from google?